# CSS - Overide Width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html where the software automatically adds the first css style `g2f0`

```
 <div class="linelevel row">
    <div class="g2f0 col-sm-6 form-group">
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="g2f1 col-sm-6 form-group">
       <label for="address">Address</label>
       <input id="address" type="text" value="" name="address">
    </div>
</div>
```

The style is incrementally auto generated and gets inserted as the first class for each div as follows depending on the number of divs there are on the page:

```
div.g2f0 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

div.g2f1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I want to get rid of the width proprty on these auto generated classes so that I can use the bootstrap grid classes. I've tried using specificity as follows but then the bootrap grid classes dont work at breakpoints:

```
<div class="linelevel row">
    <div class="g2f0 reset-width col-sm-6 form-group">
       <label for="name">Name</label>
       <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
    </div>
 </div>

.linelevel .reset-width {
    width: auto;
}
```

I've had to do the following to get it to work meaning I have to overide all break points for all grid classes:

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
   .col-sm-6 {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
 }
```

Any one know any other way where I can use a single class between `g2f0` (these are auto generated) and `col-sm-6` to remove the width from the `g2f0` class?

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say you want to use bootstrap grid, yet also want to set `width: auto` on the `div` - they would seem to be opposing goals

Comment: @rory sorry I meant I want to get rid of the width property on the `g2f0` class.

Comment: @adam78 Have you tried my answer?

Comment: I would change the title of the question to include "with auto generated html"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two classes that add width - g2f0 and col-sm-6. You have two option - remove auto adding of g2f0 class, or set custom width like Wayne showed you:

```
div.g2f0.reset-width {
    width: 200px; /*your custom width*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of your CSS files. You need to import the bootstrap css file after the file that contains the .g2f0 class .

If you can't edit the order, the ugly solution is to edit the booststrap sass/css and add !important to those withds(.col-xx-xx) or override them(.col-xx-xx) in a new other imported file. but be careful.

Comment: @Farouk I'm unable to do that becuase these classes are auto generated by the software.

Comment: If you can't edit the order, the ugly solution is to edit the booststrap sass/css and add !important to those withds(.col-xx-xx) or override them(.col-xx-xx)  in a new other imported file. but be careful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on firefox, you can simply right click page and use inspect element. After that find the find your div, see which style sheet is causing trouble, head to the style sheet line and remove the width causing problems.

Or alternatively you can just set the width of bootstrap using inline stylesheet as follows which will overide all external stylesheets

```
<div class="g2f0 reset-width col-sm-6 form-group" style="width:...%;height:...%">
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to take advantage of is CSS specificity.

If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins.

Your divide has more than one class, div.g2f0 only counts as one class while ...

```
div.g2f0.reset-width {
    width: auto;
}
```

Counts as two classes. It has a higher specificity and therefore wins.

Specificity calculator https://specificity.keegan.st/

**Another example**

```
div.g2f0.reset-width.col-sm-6 {
    width:500px;
}
div.g2f0.reset-width {
    width: auto;
}
```

Now the first CSS has 3 classes used to specify g2f0 divide and the one that follows has 2 classes. The CSS rule with the most specify says width 500px that is what will be used. Regardless of order.

... you could carefully order the CSS rules and if the specificity were the same the last applied rule would be used. But, the downside of doing it that way is that when you come back to the page in 6 months, it will not be easy to find which CSS rule is being used. A mistake down the road is more likely to happen that will cost lots of time to find.

The inspect element tools in browsers when using specificity correctly tell you which CSS rule is being used.

**Another Method is to use an ID attribute**

IDs are more specific than classes for CSS rules

```
<div class="g2f0 col-sm-6 form-group" id="reset-width">
   <label for="name">Name</label>
   <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name">
</div>

div#reset-width {
   width:auto
}
```

**Selector based on update ...**

```
div.form-group:first-child {
    width: auto;
}
```

The addition of the css3 pseudo selector first-child gives it more specificity.

**Jquery also has support for CSS4** pseudo selector "has" ... the jquery

```
$( "div" ).has( #name ).css( "width", "auto" );
```

will set the css of the div that has an ID in it with the value of name ... to width:auto

Comment: But the div will not have the ".col-sm-6" width. it will be auto.

Comment: @FAROUKBLALOU you can just add the widths after from `.col-sm-*`

Comment: yes assuming the style for .col-sm-6 width is only using one class to specify. The most specific I can get on your html is div.g2f0.reset-width.col-sm-6.form-group

Comment: @Wayne the `.g1`, `.g2` etc classes are auto generated so I cant overide them by hardcoding as I don't know what their names are going to be. All I know is they appear as the first class defined in the html.

Comment: @adam78 is only one divide going to have both of the classes reset-width and form-group? then your selector would be div.reset-width.form-group and is more specific.

Comment: @adam78 is the divide you want to select the first divide of another parent HTML tag?

Comment: @adam78 Note I've added to the answer another alternative if you can add an ID tag to the element you want to change.

Comment: @adam78 there is also an "nth-child()" selector in CSS3 if you can change the html.

Comment: @Wayne the div is inside another div with class `linelevel`. See updated html for clarification. I tried `div.reset-width.form-group { width: auto; }` but then the grid class doesnt work becuase the above class with width:auto ends up with higher specificity becuase its applied to entire

Answer (score 0):

```
div.g2f0.reset-width{width: auto !important;}
```